# What does "Dfl." stand for?

Tags: abbreviations

I'm reading an old scientific paper from the 1980s, and I'm curious about one of the abbreviations it uses in a fairly admin part of the paper:

> [image]
>
> Single issue price Dfl. 77.00, postage included.

([This](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370157386800011) is the paper, in case it's relevant.)

I [asked](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Slang/DFL.html) the [internet](http://www.gotknowhow.com/answers/what-does-the-abbreviation-dfl-mean) what the "Dfl." means but none of the answers really apply. I imagine the answer probably speaks to some bygone method of distribution of literature, which makes me more curious. Can someone clarify this?

Comment: Dutch guilder. (Dutch florin.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_guilder

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense (Elsevier is a Dutch publisher). It's curious that the international code for that currency is/was NLG, but then again that ISO standard date from around 1978 and it would have taken some time to propagate.

Comment: @E.P. ISO standards are still not always used. Letter-like symbols (like the _f_ then, and the British pound thing) remain popular nowadays. Think of the $ or US$ (USD), and the euro sign (which I never know how to produce) (EUR). Anyways,  _f_ (italics, with serif if possible, or better yet the florin sign) and fl. and _fl._ (italics) were widely used at the time in the Netherlands (think of prices at the butcher or the bakery). Dfl. (which I also recognise) was probably only used for mostly foreign markets or other international contexts.

Comment: @Keepthesemind If you're a Dutch native speaker and you can confirm that the abbreviation was in use at the time (which Wikipedia doesn't do) then that's definitely an Anwer ;-).

Comment: @E.P. Confirmed. But you may see for yourself: https://www.google.nl/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22dfl%22+%22dutch+guilder%22 (over 6,000 hits).

Comment: @Keepthesemind I meant something more on [these lines](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4569/39544).